# How to execute local javascript file using selenium webdriver in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an application where i want to execute a java script file using selenium web driver in C#. I am keeping the file as a part of application so whenever application launch, i want that js file executed.I already tried placing that js file on server but I don't want that. I want that js as a part of application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavascriptExecutor:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("[INSER JS HERE]");
```

Comment: I am already using this function but I want to run a whole javascript file not a single function. js.executeScript("[INSER JS HERE]") in this we can only run function. I tried  js.ExecuteScript("javascript:var jq = document.createElement('script');jq.src = \"file:///FILE_NAME.JS\";"); but its not working.

Comment: Hmm, not sure that is possible. Perhaps you could amend your JS file and create a kind of master function that then calls all the other functions in the JS file. Then just reference the master function using the JavascriptExecutor.